# Find special character in batch

Tags: batch-file, find

I have the following file repoinfo.tmp:

```
Revisión: 7 //(7 or any number)
```

I would like to find the number, 7 in order to create a incremental backup

My code is:

```
SET LAST_REV=

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%i in
```

(`find "Revision: " "%TEMP%\repoinfo.tmp"`) do (

```
SET LAST_REV=%%j

)
```

The problem is that my output is Spanish and character ó makes problems, maybe should I try with findstr or regular expression...

The file exactlly contains: I just take the comans output and throught a pipe I save it.
That's why the out is not 'ó'

```
Ruta: hardware
URL: http://localhost:800/hardware
Ra¡z del repositorio: http://localhost:800/hardware
UUID del repositorio: fc0eaf3c-dae0-114c-8de9-14799a96cf30
Revisi¢n: 8
Tipo de nodo: directorio
Autor del £ltimo cambio: ruben
Revisi¢n del £ltimo cambio: 8
Fecha de £ltimo cambio: 2012-10-16 17:26:39 +0200 (mar 16 de oct de 2012)
```

I changed my code and now it works, in the find argument I wrote 'Revisi¢n' and it works.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%i in
```

(`find "Revisi¢n: " "%TEMP%\repoinfo.tmp"`) do (

```
  SET LAST_REV=%%j

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using on the information you provided, I would recommend using regular expressions with findstr. Let me know if the output from the following code is what you're looking for:

```
SET LAST_REV=
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%i in (`findstr /brc:"Revisi.n: ." "%TEMP%\repoinfo.tmp"`) do (
SET LAST_REV=%%j
)
```

Comment: I need the number that follows Revisión: XXXXX store it, after that I create an incremental back-up, but basically just the number. 
"Versión" is always the same output, svn info http://XXXXXX That's the output, I search for "Versión" and get the number.

Comment: Okay did you try the code I posted? It should set `LAST_REV` to the value XXXXX that follows `Revisión: `

Comment: yes I did but the return is the character 'C'
Apparently basch doesn't admit this 'ó'

Comment: Can you add a sample file to the original post (Or the text file you are using the code with?)

Comment: I fix it. Thank you for your time. I just used the repesentatión of ó in the outputfile: 'Revisi¢n'